# Why does my new iPhone Quick Start migration have 2 different iOS requirements?

Tags: iphone, ios, error, data-transfer, setup

Old phone - iPhone 6S running iOS 11.0.3

New phone - iPhone 13

When trying to do "Quick Start" on my new iPhone, the instructions say to bring an iPhone with at least iOS 11 near to the new iPhone.

[image: iPhone Quick Start screen]

I do that, but the transfer fails and says "Transfer Not Supported.  Bring an iPhone running ***iOS 12.4*** or later nearby to start transferring data."

[image: iPhone Transfer Not Supported]

So are the original instructions are wrong and iOS 11 is not sufficient, or is there something wrong with the transfer process?

Answer (score 1):

No, nothing is wrong and it’s almost always best to update each device as far as possible before starting the transfer.

In the case of a new phone, you can set it up new with no data and update or connect to a computer and restore it. For the existing phone, once you’re sure you have a good backup, update it all the way on the current version.

Oh, most importantly, congrats on the new phone - the 13 is a powerhouse and nice step up for your kit.

Comment: I'm just going to be a stickler for detail and ask, why does it say iOS 11 at first but on failure says iOS 12.4?

Comment: Probably a bug @iwantmyphd - likely it guesses wrong and then checks online and downloads the correct info. This will be hard to test as not many devices are down level and most testing is focused on the current latest for each major version.